# Using AutoHotKey, how to change (remap) a keyboard key to run a file?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

Say I want to change the key F12 to instead open the file C:\file.txt

How can I do this using AutoHotKey?

Here is what I have that is not working:

```
F12::Run C:\file.txt
```

---

**UPDATE:** I did it wrong. I should be using a forward slash, not a back slash. First to answer with this answer an maybe give another tip, wins.

**This works:**

```
F12::Run C:/file.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct form:

```
F12::Run, C:\file.txt
```

Comment: You're Right!!! =D

Comment: @techaddict Are you new to AutoHotkey? I'm one of the local AutoHotkey fanatics here, so feel free to `@iglvzx` me in the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) if you ever need help with AHK. :)

Comment: Okay =) I have used AutoHotKey in the past, but only for very basic functions.